# How do I move a specified number of files automatically from one folder to another using PHP? (for use in WordPress plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress

Using a WordPress plugin, I have an image carousel that displays all files within a specified folder.

I only want to display the last 24 images from that folder. One way I thought I could do this without editing the original plugin is have all files from the previous day move to a new folder when the first photo from the next day arrives. The file names contain a time stamp, because of this, I can't specify actual file names, just the type of file.

Unfortunately, I am completely new to PHP and Server Side Scripting and would appreciate any advice on how to solve this issue.

Comment: This is a very broad question, we cannot teach you how to use php here, you will have to start exploring yourself. But a general advice: no not move around files for this, instead a filter mechanism to the existing code that picks the files from the file system.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't have to move the files, just read them and sort by date.

here's a conceptual how to, untested.

```
$files =[];
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
           $files[filemtime($file)] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);

    // sort in reverse order
    krsort($files);

    for($i =0; $i < 24; $i++) {
      $file = $files[$i]
      echo "<img src='".$file."' />";
    }
}
```

good luck

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is truly appreciated @Nimrod, would I merge this with the plugin's .php file . . . I understand that I am very naive when it comes to PHP but when faced with problems, one can't help but ask.

Comment: remember that you still have to code some more here, to echo the files property, into the expected html structure. notice please that the code is untested.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, You want to display only last 24 images from that folder.

You can get name of last 24 images by their modification time.

```
    $filelist = glob("/path/to/your_dir/*.{jpg,JPG,PNG,png,jpeg,JPEG}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

In php run a foreach loop for all the files in that directory, ,

```
    $i = 0;
    foreach($filelist as $key => $file){ 
       $temp_arr[$i]['mtime'] = filemtime($file); 
       $temp[$i]['filename'] = $file;
       $i++; 
    }
```

Then you can sort $temp_arr to retrive 24 latest images based on mtime.